# variable access within htmltools::withtags

Tags: r, shiny, dt

Why does the following not print the table th-elements of "names(data)"? The element stay empty. Interestingly the lapply in the tr-section does seem to work without any problem.

```
data <- data.frame(a = 1, b = 2)

htmltools::withTags(table(
  class = 'display',
  thead(
    tr(
      th(rowspan = 2, "Test1"),
      th(rowspan = 2, "Test2"),
      th(rowspan = 2, "Test3"),
      th(colspan = 2, names(data)[1]),
      th(colspan = 2, names(data)[2])
    ),
    tr(
      lapply(rep(c('Abs', 'Change'), 2), th)
    )
  )
))
```

gives:

```
<table class="display">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">Test1</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Test2</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Test3</th>
      <th colspan="2"></th> ## Why empty???
      <th colspan="2"></th> ## Why empty???
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Abs</th>
      <th>Change</th>
      <th>Abs</th>
      <th>Change</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its a problem caused by `eval` and `substitute` in combination. Lets look at the `withTags` command:

```
> htmltools::withTags
function (code) 
{
    eval(substitute(code), envir = as.list(tags), enclos = parent.frame())
}
<environment: namespace:htmltools>
```

It calls the code within this nested evaluation frame. Now we can just break down to the interesting part:

```
> eval(substitute(names(data)[1]), envir = as.list(tags))
NULL
```

This is what causes the `th` tag to remain empty. Now, **why** is this happening?

```
> names(htmltools::tags)
  [1] "a"           "abbr"        "address"     "area"        "article"    
  [6] "aside"       "audio"       "b"           "base"        "bdi"        
 [11] "bdo"         "blockquote"  "body"        "br"          "button"     
 [16] "canvas"      "caption"     "cite"        "code"        "col"        
 [21] "colgroup"    "command"     "data"        "datalist"    "dd"         
 [26] "del"         "details"     "dfn"         "div"         "dl"         
 [31] "dt"          "em"          "embed"       "eventsource" "fieldset"   
 [36] "figcaption"  "figure"      "footer"      "form"        "h1"         
 [41] "h2"          "h3"          "h4"          "h5"          "h6"         
 [46] "head"        "header"      "hgroup"      "hr"          "html"       
 [51] "i"           "iframe"      "img"         "input"       "ins"        
 [56] "kbd"         "keygen"      "label"       "legend"      "li"         
 [61] "link"        "mark"        "map"         "menu"        "meta"       
 [66] "meter"       "nav"         "noscript"    "object"      "ol"         
 [71] "optgroup"    "option"      "output"      "p"           "param"      
 [76] "pre"         "progress"    "q"           "ruby"        "rp"         
 [81] "rt"          "s"           "samp"        "script"      "section"    
 [86] "select"      "small"       "source"      "span"        "strong"     
 [91] "style"       "sub"         "summary"     "sup"         "table"      
 [96] "tbody"       "td"          "textarea"    "tfoot"       "th"         
[101] "thead"       "time"        "title"       "tr"          "track"      
[106] "u"           "ul"          "var"         "video"       "wbr"
```

As you can see, **data** is one of the tags, so it is one of the commands that are included in the environment. And now the command is evaluated withing this new set of variables. Not surprisingly:

```
> names(htmltools::tags$data)
NULL
```

This is the reason for that strange behaviour. I quote from [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/substitute.html):

> Note
>
> substitute works on a purely lexical basis. There is no guarantee that the resulting expression makes any sense.

As for **avoiding** this behaviour: It suffices to name your data.frame `data1` or anything that can not be mistaken for a html tag.